# 深層学習をさせるためにコードを書いているのですが、エラーが出てしまい進まなく、また、エラーの内容がわからないので教えていただきたいです。

Tags: python

初めまして、pythonを始めて1週間目の初心者です。
このようなコードを書いているのですが、エラーが出てしまい、ここから進むことができない状況です。エラーがそもそも何に対してのエラーを示しているのかすらわからなく非常に困っています。

コードについてはyoutube（youtu.be/i3ZIRJYlzkU）を見てそのまま書き写しているのですが、youtubeの動画の方はエラーが出ずに進まれているのですが、私が行うとエラーが出てしまいます。
どなたか解決できるかた教えていただけませんか？

```
from keras. applications. vgg16 import VGG16
from keras. models import Sequential
from keras. models import model_from_json
from keras. models import Model
from keras. layers import Input, Activations, merge, Dense, Flatten,Droput
from tensorflow. keras. optimizers import Adam

input_tensor = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
base_model = VGG16(weights=' imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False)

# 後付け

top_model = Sequential ()
top_model. add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

# 結合

model = Model(inputs=base_model. input, outputs=top_model(base_model.output))

#学習させない層

for layer in model. layers[:15]:
  layer.trainable = False

print('# layers = ', len(model. layers))

model. compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model. summary()
```

[image]

Comment: from keras. layers import Input, Activations, merge, Dense, Flatten,Droputの下にこのようなエラーが出ます。
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.

Comment: エラーメッセージはコメントではなく質問記事に追記しましょう。また参照しているYouTube動画へのリンクも追記してください。そのYouTube動画が前提としている環境やモジュールのインストール状況に合わせて学習環境を作成していますか？ それらの環境構築が完全ではないから発生しているものと思われます。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
すみません。まだ使い方がわからなくコメント欄に書いてしまいました。youtubeのリンク貼らさせていただきます。https://youtu.be/i3ZIRJYlzkU
また、環境やモジュールのインストールはいろんな動画を見てダウンロードをしたつもりなのですが、できていない可能性があります。その場合どのようにすれば環境構築できるのでしょうか？
初歩的な質問で申し訳ございません。

Comment: 引用元のコードのURLは質問を編集して質問に追記してください。質問者さんの環境（使用OS、Pythonや使用モジュールのバージョン等）も質問に追記されると回答がつきやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: merinoさん、kinifさん, cubickさんご教授ありがとうございます。
もう一度書き直して行なったところ実行が正しく行えたのでタイプミスだったと思います。
OSなどの追加情報を追加情報を明記しようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

typoが原因ですね。

`Activations`の最後の`s`が余計です。
そして`Droput`では`o`が抜けていて正しくは`Dropout`です。

それから動画作成時から状況が変化しているのか、`merge`をimport出来ないようです。
質問に提示された部分のソースコードでは`merge`を使っていないようですので、それは削除しても良いかもしれません。
ただし今後`merge`を使う場合は書き変える必要があるでしょう。

該当の行は以下のようになるのでは？

```
from keras. layers import Input, Activation, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
```